# Getting a "reference" to a dict or list value when it is an immutable object

Tags: python

When using a dictionary, I find myself wanting to iterate over the values and change them in some way.  I've been writing for loops over the `myDict.keys()` and then making changes to the `myDict['key']`.  Particularly if I need to make many changes to the value in each iteration, I end up typing a lot of verbose bracket syntax to get at the same value in the dictionary over and over.  Making nested objects only makes the problem worse. What is the best-practice for making an "alias" or a "reference" to a value in a dictionary, even if the type of the value is immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the object in a variable.  It will reference the exact same value stored in the dictionary.

```
x = dictionary['nested']['keys']
# Do stuff with x
```

If it's a mutable object, any changes you make to `x` will affect the value in the dictionary.  If it's an immutable object, you can't make any changes anyway, so it doesn't matter.

If you want to be able to actually set the immutable object that the dictionary references, but you don't want to have to keep referring to the dictionary keys, you can use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) and [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) libraries to dynamically make getter and setter partial function objects

```
from operator import getitem, setitem
from functools import partial

d = {'a': {'b': 1}}
getter = partial(getitem, d['a'], 'b')
setter = partial(setitem, d['a'], 'b')

print getter()
# 1
setter(2)
print d
# {'a': {'b': 2}}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested in making this work with immutable, and while I understand that I'm never changing the immutable and just replacing it, I'd like some sort of syntax that allows your code example to put X to the left of any assignment operators and always affect the value in the dict (or replace it, in the case of immutable).